# Sell Excel file securely

Tags: excel, license-key

I would like to sell an Excel file online. The main security goal is: one user / download.

I thought of an individual license key per download combined with somehow restricting the user to copy the content of the Excel file but at the same time make it possible to add content.

Any suggestions how to accomplish that or even have a better idea to solve the problem?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Excel is not the solution as there are many problems with your approach.   Any security you put on the Excel file can be removed.

Comment: Apart from @Sorceri point, what if the user simply distributes the file with the license key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at LockXLS. I've used with some success. As others have mentioned, there is no built in way to protect your spreadsheet. Anyone can google how to use a hex editor to unlock Excel sheets and be on their merry way with your hard work in a matter of minutes, even if you are using some sort of vba protection. LockXLS is the best way I found to adequately protect a spreadsheet, but it does come with its own set of quirks. Download the trial and try it out. http://www.lockxls.com/product.asp